# What IP address do I use to make my site publicly visible Amazon VPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2

I have a Windows 2012 VPS from Amazon EC2 services, and I have a domain I created under IIS, I was wondering I tried both public and private IP address in the host to make it go live. I tried it on localhost, it works, but I try it on my other computer and it does not. I was wondering what IP address do I use to make it public?

Information requested by E.J. Brennan

I just did the basic steps, created a folder with a page (For now just letting people know this domain is in use) then I added it to IIS using add website, I clicked enable, I went into the hosts file and added the lines for it. Then I accessed it in localhost. But when I go to try to add a public IP it is not access it gives domain doesnt exist. I used to private and public IP. I dont know what else to do

Comment: For pete's sake, if you need information let me know, just answer my question so I can go home.

Answer (score 0):

The public IP is the one that is going to be used, not the private one.

If you can't access the website by typing the public ip into your browser (from your local computer), there could be lots of reasons - but we would need more information about what you have done so far in terms of setup. Just having a public ip isn't necessarily enough.

Comment: I see. Thank you for answering, I just did the basic steps, created a folder with a page (For now just letting people know this domain is in use) then I added it to IIS using add website, I clicked enable, I went into the hosts file and added the lines for it. Then I accessed it in localhost. But when I go to try to add a public IP it is not access it gives domain doesnt exist. I used to private and public IP. I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Do you want me to add that to the question?

Comment: Okay I binded the pubic IP, however, the problem still persists. I can access the page in the VPS, but not on my other computer. It still gives dns not found.

Comment: if you're browsing directly by IP, you shouldn't be going via dns. Can you access the site if you put the ip directly in the address bar? Does the ip respond to ping?

Comment: No. Not from my local computer or the amazon vps

Comment: Gave site took to long to respond.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan what do you think I should do?

Comment: It works on localhost, but not when I access it from another computer, regardless of the IP. Also @hairmot I did make it to where it gets accessed by a website name such as www.testing.com

Comment: you say it works via localhost - do you mean you are browsing to 'localhost' or you are browsing to the ip FROM the local machine?

Comment: also check you dont have a firewall blocking port 80/443

Comment: Browsing from the VPS itself. From the actual machine using the website name... i.e... www.smartleadtools.com

Comment: Do I find those settings in IIS? Cause I am browsing the web right now and I am not in my VPS machine.

Comment: Can you ping the ip address at all from your local machine?

Comment: Basic steps are: make sure your local firewall is blocking it, make sure the aws security that the instance uses allows traffic in - at least on port 80 and/or 443 if using ssl and finally you need to make sure the vpc the ec2 instance is in has an Internet gateway setup so it has access to the 'outside world'

Comment: How can I do that actually? I have never used amazon until now. @E.J.Brennan

Comment: @E.J.Brennan do I configure those settings in the amazon console? Or the actual VPS machine where the site is located at?

Comment: The firewall (if you have one), on the EC2 instance - everything else in the aws console.